# Insert XML elements into SQL table in same order as XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I'm transferring XML files to SQL TABLES - I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. I'm trying to have my XML elements be inserted into the same order they were in the XML file.

For example XML code is:

```
<form>
  <ItemType>New Regular</ItemType>
  <FirstBuyDate>02/01/2007</FirstBuyDate>
  <FirstShipDate>02/05/2007</FirstShipDate>
  <ItemBrand>Gillette Blade/Razors</ItemBrand>
  <ItemDescription>...</ItemDescription>
  <Size>8.00</Size>
  <InnerOffInvoice />
  <MasterOffInvoice />
  <PalletItems>
  <ID>908402</ID> 
  <PalletShipDate>04/03/13</PalletShipDate>
  </PalletItems>
  <ReviewComments />
</form>
```

On this particutlar part of my project. I am extracting the column names from my XML file. I am using the (/form/*) to extract only XML columns names be put into a table. However the thing I'm struggling with is how to have the xml elements be inserted in the same order they are in the XML file. Currently they are randomly inserted into the column:

```
    Items
1. FirstBuyDate
2. Size
3. ItemType
4. PalletItems... etc.
```

I want to be like:

```
    Items
1. ItemType
2. FirstBuyDate 
3. FirstShipDate
4. ItemBrand... etc.
```

I added this line `('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int')` trying to put a count on them. It sort of works... however it is duplicating some numbers. I am not sure why? Can any of you help me?

```
SELECT distinct Parent.Items.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int') as [Index],
Parent.Items.value('local-name(../.)', 'varchar(100)') as 'ParentItem',
    Parent.Items.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as 'ChildItem'
FROM    dbo.FormResults
CROSS APPLY xmlformfields.nodes('/form/*')  as Parent(Items)
order by ParentItem, [Index]
```

See here - I'm getting duplicate Index Numbers -- Do you know why?

[image]

Thanks!!

Added Code implementing suggestion below:

```
declare @YourNumberTable table (n int primary key);
insert into @YourNumberTable
select top 100 row_number()over(order by number) from master..spt_values;

SELECT distinct 
Parent.Items.value('local-name(../.)', 'varchar(100)') as 'ParentItem',
Parent.Items.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as 'ChildItem'
FROM    dbo.FormResults
CROSS APPLY xmlformfields.nodes('/form/*')  as Parent(Items)

select  [position] = n.n,
        [nodeName] = p.n.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from    @YourNumberTable n
cross apply   FormResults.xmlformfields.nodes('/form/*[position()=sql:column("n")]') p(n)
where   n.n <= FormResults.xmlformfields.value('count(/form/*)', 'int');
```

I am not sure how to combine these two tables?

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I forgot about that important detail! I'll edit my entry!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a number table to attach a node position.  Then use this position with your insert.

```
declare @YourNumberTable table (n int primary key);
insert into @YourNumberTable
    select top 100 row_number()over(order by number) from master..spt_values;


declare @x xml;
set @x = '<form>
  <ItemType>New Regular</ItemType>
  <FirstBuyDate>02/01/2007</FirstBuyDate>
  <FirstShipDate>02/05/2007</FirstShipDate>
  <ItemBrand>Gillette Blade/Razors</ItemBrand>
  <ItemDescription>...</ItemDescription>
  <Size>8.00</Size>
  <InnerOffInvoice />
  <MasterOffInvoice />
  <PalletItems>
  <ID>908402</ID> 
  <PalletShipDate>04/03/13</PalletShipDate>
  </PalletItems>
  <ReviewComments />
</form>';

select  [position] = n.n,
        [nodeName] = p.n.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from    @YourNumberTable n
cross
apply   @x.nodes('/form/*[position()=sql:column("n")]') p(n)
where   n.n <= @x.value('count(/form/*)', 'int');
```

**EDIT:** Since your XML is stored as column you can access in much the same way:

```
declare @FormResults table (Id int primary key, xmlformfields xml);
insert into @FormResults
    select 1, '<form><ItemType>New Regular</ItemType><FirstBuyDate>02/01/2007</FirstBuyDate><FirstShipDate>02/05/2007</FirstShipDate><ItemBrand>Gillette Blade/Razors</ItemBrand></form>' union all
    select 2, '<form><one>Hello</one><two>World</two></form>'

select  [Id] = fr.Id,
        [Position] = n.n,
        [ParentNodeName] = p.n.value('local-name(..)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
        [NodeName] = p.n.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from    @FormResults fr
join    @YourNumberTable n on 
        fr.xmlformfields.value('count(/form/*)', 'int') >= n.n
cross
apply   fr.xmlformfields.nodes('/form/*[position()=sql:column("n")]') p(n)
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, 

Thanks for your comments. How would I approach this if my XML is not an OPENXML? I am pulling it from a SQL column - xmlformfields column from the table FormResults. I have added some code to my entry above. 

Thanks

Comment: Added another example for you